# why would ldconfig create a symlink to libselinux.so.1 from libext2fs.so.2?

Tags: strace, audit, malware, ldconfig

using `strace` I have found a behaviour of `ldconfig` (glibc), I can make no sense of

```
lstat("/usr/lib/libext2fs.so.2", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=16, ...}) = 0
unlink("/usr/lib/libext2fs.so.2")       = 0
symlink("libselinux.so.1", "/usr/lib/libext2fs.so.2") = 0
```

Is there any need to have the shared object library for `ext2fs` (`libext2fs.so.2`) to be a symbolic link to `libselinux.so.1`.

How does ldconfig know what to do? It does not seem logical to me that 
this static binary `/usr/bin/ldconfig` would have such a behaviour hardcoded, right. However its configuration file `/etc/ld.so.conf` does not help me much to clear that mystery.

What makes all of this even more confusing/suspicious with my distros tools (Arch Linux) I cannot find any package the file belongs to.

```
$ pkgfile /usr/lib/libselinux.so.1
```

does not show any package, while 
    $ pkgfile /usr/lib/libext2fs.so

outputs `core/e2fsprogs`

So my question is specifically:

1. what the role of this libselinux.so.1 is here
2. how ldconfig comes to decide to create that symlink (which btw. breaks `e2fsck`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your library was probably renamed by mistake at some time from `/usr/lib/libselinux.1` to `/usr/lib/libext2fs.so.2` . This doesn't prevent *ldconfig* to find the expected name from the library's content (rather than the library's file name) and thus link the "correct" name. This can be verified by copying any library to some directory and ask *ldconfig* to update (only) this directory.

Here the equivalent on Debian 9:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ cp -aL /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 /tmp/foo/libmytest.so.2
$ ls -l /tmp/foo/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 155400 Sep 24  2017 /tmp/foo/libmytest.so.2
$ /sbin/ldconfig -v -n /tmp/foo
/tmp/foo:
    libselinux.so.1 -> libmytest.so.2 (changed)
$ ls -l /tmp/foo/*
-rw-r--r-- 1 test test 155400 Sep 24  2017 /tmp/foo/libmytest.so.2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 test test     14 Jun  5 23:33 /tmp/foo/libselinux.so.1 -> libmytest.so.2
```

By the way *libselinux* is a common library for software dealing with  [SELinux](https://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page). Even the `ls`, `cp`, `mv`, `ps` commands are usually linked with it (for their respective `-Z` option).

Comment: Your answer rings true. I have looked `readelf  --dynamic /usr/lib` does indeed output ` 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libext2fs.so.2]`, also I have checked that somewhere burried in .bash_history there is indeed some evidence that the `libselinux.so.1` file was created as a copy of then `libext2fs.so.2` file, making this occurence less likely something malicious (what a relief). I now have to look into how the ldcache works, since the strace suggest that ldconfig did not check the file's content but simply by the values returned by stat ldconfig guessed what to do.